# 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid error when using Amazon SES with phpmailer

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmailer, amazon-ses

Under SES I've created new SMTP credentials and I've got
a new SES Access Key, SMTP username and SMTP Passowrd.

I'm trying to send email using the SMTP usernmae/password
but I get an error:  535 Authentication Credentials Invalid

Under IAM > Access Management, I can see it has access
for SES-sending.
[image]

I don't have any special character in the SMTP password
so it's not an issue of URL-Encoding.

Here is my simple code:

```
<?php
       use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
       use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
       require '/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php';

       $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
       $mail->IsSMTP();
       $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
       $mail->Host = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
       $mail->Port = 587; 
       $mail->Username = "my-smtp-username";
       $mail->Password = "my-smtp-password";
       $mail->IsHTML(true);
       $mail->SetFrom("some-random-name@sudomain.mydomain.com", "display-name");
       $mail->Subject = "Test";
       $mail->Body = "hello";
       $mail->AddAddress("recipent@example-domain.com");

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
           echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
           echo "Message has been sent";
        }
?>
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and you’ll be able to see what the server is saying.

Comment: More details but it's the same: 2021-12-25 14:56:28 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid

Comment: Pease show all the debug output.

Comment: @IsaacChen, Can you confirm you have created the credentials in the region where you are using them. SMTP credentials are region-specific.